# Eclipse installing software stuck at 0%

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just installed the Goclipse plugin from

http://goclipse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/goclipse-update-site/

And I realized that this is not the version I need, so I uninstalled it, and a restart-required window popup, and I clicked "restart now"

However, the eclipse just disappeared and did not show up again for a long time, so I started it manually, and another eclipse instance showed up soon after that.

Now, I cannot install new plugins, and it would stuck at "Installing Software - 0%" forever! (Nor can I cancel the installation. ...)

[image: Installing software stuck at 0%]

What can I do? Please, I really don't want re-installation! >_<

Comment: I know it's cliched, but have you tried rebooting your computer?

Comment: If the ctrl+alt+del solution below worked, then restarting the computer would have worked as well. The reason why rebooting your computer should ALWAYS be one of the first solutions you try is because a lot of the time errors happen because of weird interactions between programs and restarting is the easiest way to fix that because it closes ALL the programs and clears the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl-Alt-Delete andkill all instances of Java and Eclipse.  Restart Eclipse.

Comment: I had thought shutdown the Eclipse instance would do all the work. ... Silly me. ...

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen *until* it revealed that some updates were available. It seems Eclipse will only allow one of these processes at once. Force it to find and install (or reject) updates first, and then try to install your new software.